# Conditionally call Linq extension method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an abstract class that implement all of my queries. My Get function is:

```
public virtual List<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> criteria)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(criteria).OrderByDescending(OrderBy).ThenBy(ThenOrderBy).ToList();
}
```

And the ThenOrderBy property is:

```
public virtual Func<TEntity, object> ThenOrderBy { get; set; }
```

The **OrderBy** property is required, but my new property, **ThenOrderBy** is not required and not implemented in all classes that inherits this abstract class.

I am getting this error:

> Value can not be null

Is there any way to mantain this clean code without putting blocks of "if's" statments?

**Solution that I Used:**

```
public virtual List<TEntity> Consultar(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> criteria)
{
    var query = _dbSet.Where(criteria);
    query = OrderDescending ?
            query.OrderByDescending(OrderBy).AndOptionallyBy(ThenOrderBy) 
            : 
            query.OrderBy(OrderBy).AndOptionallyBy(ThenOrderBy);
    query = (paggedSearch && Skip > 0) ? query.Skip(Skip) : query;
    query = (paggedSearch && Take > 0) ? query.Take(Take) : query;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

And Created a new Extension Class

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> AndOptionallyBy<TSource, TKey>(this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        return (keySelector == null) ? source : source.ThenBy(keySelector);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why *not* put blocks of if statements? What you wrote is just a list of function calls. If you want them to occur according to a set of conditions, you use conditional expressions. It would be different if you used query syntax, but here you are just using function calls

Comment: You could create your own extension method that applies `ThenBy` if the lambda isn't null, or returns the original IQueryable if it is.

Comment: You only have long code because you're repeating yourself all over the place. Do the Skip/Take stuff afterwards just once

Comment: The line `IEnumerable<TEntity> query = _dbSet.Where(criteria);` will cause the query to execute without ordering or paging. Casting an IQueryable to an IEnumerable executes the query. You should use `var query = _dbSet.Where(criteria);` or `IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet.Where(criteria);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos IQueryable is an IEnumerable - just putting IEnumerable on the LHS wont cast it.

Comment: @Jamiec sorry, I just freak instinctively whenever I see queryables treated as enumerables

Comment: @Luis you are *still* repeating yourself. You don't have to repeat `query.OrderBy` at all. Check my answer - you just need 3 conditionals

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right, TKS!!!! I am posting the updated code

Comment: Next time, ask the question you want to ask the first time. This is not "please edit your answer with every edit of my question". Anyway, you **still** have repeated code. I'll leave it up to you to apply the patterns given to you in the answers. Also, searching the web for "linq conditionally apply order and paging" will yield plenty of results.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am now coding to clean repetition in Order by with your suggestion

Comment: @CodeCaster You are right, I am doing it to have a final question with best code. I will remove the updates.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks very much, your anwser is what I was looking for. Working like a charm. The others solutions are great, but I was looking for something like you posted.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there any way to use IOrderedEnumerable instead of IOrderedQueryable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own `AndOptionallyBy` method that applies the second condition if supplied, or leaves the IOrderedQueryable as is otherwise, eg:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> AndOptionallyBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
{
    if (keySelector==null)
    {
        return source;
    }
    else
    {
        return source.ThenBy(keySelector);
    }
}
```

I wouldn't use this though. While this allows you to use function chaining, it will surprise maintainers of your code.

On the one hand you have :

```
var result = _dbSet.Where(criteria)
                   .OrderByDescending(OrderBy)
                   .AndOptionallyBy(ThenOrderBy)
                   .ToList();
```

On the other

```
var query = _dbSet.Where(criteria)
                  .OrderByDescending(OrderBy);
if (ThenOrderBy!=null)
{
    query = query.ThenBy(ThenOrderBy);
}
var result = query.ToList();
```

Which do you think is clearer to someone else?

**UPDATE**

It's easy to create a paging query using conditionals:

```
var query = _dbSet.Where(criteria);
var orderedQuery=OrderDescending 
                       ?query.OrderByDescending(OrderBy)
                       :query.OrderBy(OrderBy);
if (buscaPaginada)
{
    if (Skip > 0)
    {
        query = query.Skip(Skip);
    }
    if (Take >0)
    {
        query = query.Skip(Skip);
    }
}
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: That's it! Only if you add the `OrderBy` and `ThenOrderBy` members should be `Expression<Func<...>>` instead of `Func<...>` which turns the query into `Enumerable`.

Comment: I just copied [Queryable.ThenBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535112(v=vs.110).aspx)'s own trick, ie its signature. Oh, you mean `OrderByDescending`!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your custom method (you have my vote btw), just the OP (caller) members are using incorrect type.

Answer (score 5):

No, you need to block it with an if. However, you can build up your EF queries without hitting the database:

```
public virtual List<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> criteria)
{
    var query = _dbSet.Where(criteria);

    if(OrderBy != null)
    {
        query = query.OrderByDescending(OrderBy);

        if(ThenOrderBy != null)
        {
            query = query.ThenBy(ThenOrderBy);
        }
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: slowpoke but still a mistake `!-` should be `!=`

Comment: This doesn't compile by the same reason as in my comment to CodeCaster's answer.

Comment: You are missing the point. `ThenBy` in all LINQ dialects is defined on `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` or `IOrderedQueryable<T>` (note `Ordered`).

Answer (score 4):

If short then:

```
public virtual List<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> criteria)
{ 
     var result = _dbSet.Where(criteria).OrderByDescending(OrderBy);
     if(ThenOrderBy != null)
     {
        result = result.ThenBy(ThenOrderBy);
     }
     return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I stopped using ifs without braces when I found a colleague's refactored code that accidentally called only 1 line instead of 10 because of missing braces.

Comment: @MegaTron I posted that comment to the [first revision of your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9a477c59-89d7-4b0e-b5f7-f348b47f9046/view-source), where you tried to condense a lot of logic onto three unmaintainable, unreadable lines of code. Generally, when you need to do that, you're doing that because you want to copy-paste it all over the place, which I don't find a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the cleanest solution *is* using a bunch of `if()` statements. In this case you can check whether the `ThenOrderBy` is null:

```
public virtual List<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> criteria)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> recordsToReturn = _dbSet.Where(criteria);

    if (OrderBy != null)
    {
        var orderedRecordsToReturn = recordsToReturn.OrderByDescending(OrderBy);
        recordsToReturn = orderedRecordsToReturn;

        // You can only call ThenBy() on an IOrderedQueryable
        if (ThenOrderBy != null)
        {
            recordsToReturn = orderedRecordsToReturn.ThenBy(ThenOrderBy);
        }
    }

    return recordsToReturn.ToList();
}
```

Sure, there are ways to abuse syntax to *condense* this code, but being explicit about what is happening makes code easier to read, hence cleaner.

Comment: Of course this doesn't compile because `ThenBy` is not defined for `IQueryable<T>`. Also OP should change the return type of the `OrderBy` and `ThenOrderBy` members to `Expression<Func<...>>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `ThenBy` to have a default behavior then just default it to something which will have no effecton the ordering instead of `null`. For example `entity => 1`

I tested it like the below, which allows me to not set `OrderBy` or `ThenOrderBy` and it still all works as expected:

```
public class TestClass<TEntity>
{
    private IEnumerable<TEntity> data;

    public TestClass(IEnumerable<TEntity> data){
        OrderBy = (t) => 1;
        ThenOrderBy = (t) => 1;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Func<TEntity, bool> criteria){
        return data.Where(criteria).OrderBy(OrderBy).ThenBy(ThenOrderBy);
    }
    public Func<TEntity, object> OrderBy { get; set; }
    public Func<TEntity, object> ThenOrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

Live example (you can uncomment the `ThenOrderBy` line to see it working with/without) : http://rextester.com/YFOB38755

---

By the way, your existing code could be made *much* more readable/simple:

```
public virtual List<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> criteria)
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> query = _dbSet.Where(criteria);
    query = OrderDescending ? query.OrderByDescending(OrderBy) : query.OrderBy(OrderBy)
    if (paggedSearch)
    {            
        if(Skip > 0)
            query = query.Skip(Skip);
        if(Take > 0)
            query = query.Take(Take);
    }    
    return query.ToList();
}
```

There was no need to keep repeating yourself (DRY!)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its  TEST CLASS! I dont have a database queryable. It would work appropriately if I did have an `IQueryable`

Comment: Such test code ends up copied verbatim in production code. You don't need a database to use `IQueryable<>` either. You could store an array of entities to `IQueryable<TEntity> data` for testing

Comment: It's very easy to write correct code that works with or without a database, simply by using IQueryable instead of IEnumerable